# CakePHP built-in way to get array with a (unique) table field values as keys?

Tags: php, cakephp, orm

Is there a built-in way in CakePHP to achieve this?

From table:

```
id, name
23, john
57, anna
```

Get:

```
[ 23: {name: "john"}, 
  57: {name: "anna"} ]
```

PS: I know how to program this myself, just want to know if it's already done.

Comment: What CakePHP version are you on?

Comment: also please share how you did that manually ? ;)

Comment: @Er.KT You would loop the query results, and add the result row to an array using the key value as the array key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [Custom Find Type](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#creating-custom-find-types), but it may be a bit overkill.

With the help of the [`Hash`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/hash.html#hash) class, you can achieve this quite easily:

```
$users=$this->User->find('all');
$result = Hash::combine($users,'{n}.User.id',array('{name: "%s"}','{n}.User.name'));
```